# Mount VirtualBox VDI disk

Tags: linux, virtualbox, mount, vdi

I have a virtual Windows 7 computer using VirtualBox on a Linux host. How can I mount this virtual pc's harddisk (VDI file) in Linux? It's a dynamic file, meaning that it only takes up as much space as is actually used.

Comment: I also want to know more about this. So far, the only way I coul dsee would be to actually start the VM, setup a shared directory, and put files there.

Comment: This is a duplicate of the question: http://serverfault.com/questions/210684/how-do-you-mount-a-vdi-image-on-linux.

Comment: @IsaacSutherland This question is more than a year older than that one.

Comment: @BartvanHeukelom The top-ranked answer at the serverfault.com question works for me. Should I have copied thkala's answer to this thread?

Answer (score 5):

it looks like [vdfuse](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/vdfuse.1.html) is the tool you are looking for. At least for Ubuntu (and possibly Debian) hosts. If you want to compile yourself (2010 source) you can [do that too](http://robsworldoftech.blogspot.com/2010/11/mounting-any-virtualbox-supported-vdi.html). Sources seem to be [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xspect3d/files/gordstuff/).

To install in Ubuntu use `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-fuse`

There is also a script [vdimount](http://code.google.com/p/vdimount/) script on Google Code.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore as of 2013 as the package was removed.
And the script you mention only mounts fixed sized images.

Comment: It still seems to be on launchpad: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/amd64/virtualbox-fuse

Comment: ```virtualbox-fuse``` has been removed from Debian.

Answer (score 3):

[VDI is a complex format](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=8046) and AFAIK there's *currently no software* that can directly mount a dynamic VDI image, although [there are plenty to converting it from/to other formats](http://blogs.oracle.com/VirtualGuru/entry/convert_amp_import_vm_virtual).

I hope to be wrong (or be wrong in the future, such as when someone writes that piece of software) and I'll take a look at this thread just in case ;-)

Comment: vdfuse works as of Ubuntu 12.04 (didn't test on any other version) for dynamic images too. Haven't tested one with snapshots yet

Answer (score 2):

I always wanted to know, if I could do that. Here is a very informative link >> http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=4748.

So it seems **you can mount only fixed sized VDI** files in both windows and linux.

Comment: not anymore. I successfully mount variable size VDI using vdfuse

Answer (score 1):

I came across this page while looking for a way to mount dynamic VDI files.  I'm still looking.  There is a commercial product available for Windows called [WinMount](http://www.winmount.com/) that claims to do it.  This doesn't help me (or you), but may help others who also stumble upon this web page.